# Pinging in Linux terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, grep, ping

I am looking for a command for Linux terminal in order to ping an internal server.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question probably better belongs to https://serverfault.com . `ping` command itself can't do this but you can write a small convenience script that loops until five `ping -c1 soren` attempts are successful.

Comment: Crossposting: https://askubuntu.com/q/1274405/336375

Comment: Crossposting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/608988/74329

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
ping soren | awk '/ from /{if(c==5){exit}; c++} {print}'
```

This will output all rows until five times  `from`  is found.